# How to fix "401Array{"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}" error in PHP/Sendgrid/Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku, sendgrid

**BROWSER ERROR is: 401Array{"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied, wrong credentials","field":null,"help":null}]}**

I have written this code to send an email using sendgrid addon of heroku. Instead of api_key I wrote my own. **What is the problem? Why such error?**

```
require("sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php");

$from = new SendGrid\Email(null, "kesursweta@yahoo.com");
$subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid PHP Library!";
$to = new SendGrid\Email(null, "kesursweta@yahoo.com");
$content = new SendGrid\Content("text/plain", "Hello, Email!");
$mail = new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content);

$apiKey = getenv('my_api_key');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->headers();
echo $response->body();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try out running this code with composer and then create and set SENDGRID_API_KEY. After performing both this task your code will not show any error.For reference please checkout this links:

Download composer from here: https://gist.github.com/tomysmile/3b37ab4a1ddd604093fe724d0a882166
How to create and set API_KEY: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php